# parsing json through postman to mongoose schema but its format is not valid

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

```
const Item = mongoose.model('Item',new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true,
        minlength:1,
        maxlength:55

    },
    authorsIds:{
        type:[
            new mongoose.Schema({
            name:{
                type:String,
                required:true,
                minlength:3,
                maxlength:55
            }
        })]
    }
```

i am trying assign values through postman to authorsIds as
    `"authorsIds":[{"name":"omer"} , {"name":"ali"}]` ,
but its not accepted plz helpout the right way

Comment: please show the code that doesn't work. Are you updating a mongodb document?  are you creating it? Also, your `authorsIds` has a type key before it has an array..

Comment: iauthorsIds:{
        type:[
            new mongoose.Schema({
            name:{
                type:String,
                required:true,
                minlength:3,
                maxlength:55
            }
        })]

Comment: i am just creating authorsIds through postman but its not working.. I dont know how to give values to authorsIds

Comment: You can successfully insert an `item` through postman, but the `item` does not contain `authorsIds` right? Or you can't insert at all if you have `authorsIds` field?

Comment: item contains authorsIds subdocument... and value of name in authorsIds field is not inserted thats the problem

Comment: It's still not clear to me what exactly got inserted. Only part of a document, or non is inserted at all?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman better way to achieve what you are trying is to use reference and keep two different schemas, so you can create author differently and link it to item.

Comment: @Nayan thank you ..that will be the right approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should keep two different schemas with item schema having reference of the author.

```
const Item = mongoose.model('Item',new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true,
        minlength:1,
        maxlength:55

    },
    authorsIds:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Author",
        required: true, //to make it compulsory
    }] // array of author ids , to only have single author remove []
}

const Author = mongoose.model('Author',new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true,
        minlength:3,
        maxlength:55
    }
}
```

After that in post request, you can send whole data and create authors first then put those ids in an array and create the item object.